# Is there a site that covers questions about developer behavior?

Tags: discussion

> I recently found an article about a kind of 'sickness' under
>   developers that they don't Google before they ask a question but just
>   ask the question without trying to do research. I'm in a Facebook
>   group about PHP and 9/10 of all the questions could've been solved by
>   just searching on Google.
>
> Anyway, I was saying that he should Google it first and then he said
>   that 'I should chill'. So now I want him to read the article but I
>   can't find it anymore.
>
> Does anybody know which article I'm talking about?

Where should I post this question?

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to make a good question anywhere as it stands.

Answer (score 3):

Asking folks where an off-site resource can be found is generally not on-topic on any of our current sites.

There are *rare* exceptions to this when what you're seeking is arcane documentation that eludes even the most super of sleuths. There was a bit of this that was well-received when Oracle acquired Java and started changing the sites around without redirects, figuring out where some of that went became a *very* practical problem to solve for some folks.

Right now, though, your question boils down to:

> I read this somewhere, but can't remember where, does anyone know?

And there's just not a lot of lasting value to be had (though, we'd love to help jog your memory if we could) - it's not a great fit for us.

You might try chat - in fact I think I remember reading the very same article, so it's entirely possible someone might fish it out of their bookmarks. It's actually bugging *me* a bit now, because it's right on the 'tip' of my memory.